# Adding values to a Dictionary using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class

```
class a
{  
    private Dictionary <int , string> m_Dict = new Dictionary<int , string>();
}
```

from some other component/class need to add values to the m_Dict dictionary using reflection! How do i do it ? i searched and tried but was not successfull.

Comment: Reflection?  Give a man a hammer and everything looks like a nail!...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to access the private member "m_Dict"?

```
a x = new a();

Dictionary dic = (Dictionary) x.GetType()
                  .GetField("m_Dict",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
                  .GetValue(x);

// do something with "dic"
```

But this is VERY bad design

Comment: Agreed but try putting some unit tests around EWS Managed API without doing this.

Comment: I found this useful when serializing ambiguous Dict<string,int> pairs from the Firebase Database Unity SDK into Dict<string,ObscuredInt> (To defeat most memory hacks). 
I'm still slightly worried that this is bad design though due to your comment. Should I post a question? I feel with the proliferation of firebase mobile apps, custom object serialization via reflection with type conversion is a necessary evil.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary is a pain, since it doesn't implement `IList` (something I was moaning about just the other evening). It really comes down to what you have available. Resolving the `Add` method for `int`/`string` is easy enough, but if you are dealing with typical list reflection you'll need the `Add` method from `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`.

For standard usage:

```
object data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
object key = 123;
object value = "abc";
var add = data.GetType().GetMethod("Add", new[] {
          key.GetType(), value.GetType() });
add.Invoke(data, new object[] { key, value });
```